# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElement') on wp.element.createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress plugin using ReactJS and I have these two files:

**index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "./App";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    let container = document.getElementById("mcw-first");

    if (typeof container !== 'undefined' && container !== null) {
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, container);
    }
});
```

And **App.js**:

```
function App() {
    return (
      <div>Test div</div>
    );
  }
  
  export default App;
```

But the console of my browser outputs this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElement')
    at HTMLDocument.eval (index.js:23:46)
```

[image]

I'm using webpack to compile all the files into a single JavaScript file.

What is going on? I've seen other people with the same error but their problem was that they used `import { React } from 'react'` instead of the correct form `import React from 'react'` as I do...

Also where does come from `wp.element`? I'm pretty sure it's some WordPress thing but why is it compiled in there in the React `index.js` file?

Edit:
I have found out that this methodology I use works for the WordPress admin page (react components are being printed out without errors) but it's on the public pages of the WordPress website that this doesn't work. So I'm guessing it's more like a WordPress conflict type of thing? I'm not sure.